# Автор - составитель книги

Tags: пунктуация

Если я правильно понимаю, здесь нужно тире с пробелами, а не дефис?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Автор-составитель, сложное слово, пишется через дефис.

Например: В.В. Кунин, автор-составитель  томов "Жизнь Пушкина" и "Друзья Пушкина".

Comment: Да, но в выражении "страны -- участницы конференции" ставится тире, в то время как конструкция "страны-участницы" требует дефисного написания.

Comment: (1) Страны - участники конференции. Здесь ставится одно тире (так называемое тире-дефис). В этом случае приложение имеет более конкретный характер, чем определяемое слово, которое часто бывает словом с неопределенным значением (произношение без характерной для тире паузы). ПРИМЕРЫ: Специальное устройство –  акваланг используется при работе подводников. Источник силы от матери – родной земли нам представляется важнейшим.  (2) Автор-составитель (чего)книги, здесь только дефис.

Comment: >> так называемое тире-дефис

А можно ссылочку?

Comment: Правила Лопатина, обособление приложений: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120. Правда, он такое название не использует, но примеры у него те же. Автор термина, скорее всего,Розенталь или Валгина, надо искать. (Но точно не я придумала).